# lldb reports my remote aarch64 paltform as x86_64 (AOSP)

Tags: android-source, remote-debugging, lldb

I'm trying to remotely debug a process on my aarch64 hardware.  Why does the triplet start with x86_64?  I would expect `aarch64`

```
(lldb) platform select remote-android
  Platform: remote-android
 Connected: no

(lldb) platform connect connect://localhost:5039
  Platform: remote-android
    Triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-android
OS Version: 30 (5.4.47-07670-gd50c0c10c465)
  Hostname: localhost
 Connected: yes
WorkingDir: /
    Kernel: #136 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 26 11:09:46 EST 2020
```

My Android hardware is aarch64.  I pushed lldb-server to the target with

```
adb push prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r383902b/runtimes_ndk_cxx/aarch64/lldb-server /data/local/tmp/lldb-server
```

Ran it with:

```
adb shell /data/local/tmp/lldb-server platform --listen "*:5039" --server
```

And connected with lldb (from `prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r383902b/bin/lldb`)

I am able to attach to processes on the target, even list processes (which show x86_64 triplets again to my confusing) but I can't add any symbols files, or `target create`.  Those commands yield arch errors which is what led me back to the triplet in the platform command.  (side note, I do build with `-Wl,--build-id=sha1 -g -glldb`)

When I see tutorials online, they're triplets report arm.

Notes:

- Everything is done from the shell (no IDE),
- Not running in Docker,
- My hardware is rooted and even in permissive mode right now
- Everything here is based on AOSP 11
- clang tag: `clang-r383902b`

Comment: This seems due to the version of clang :(  I see something similar happened years ago too ([see here](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/lldb-dev/2015-June/007635.html)).  My issue went away when I pulled straight from master and got the clang tag `clang-r399163b`

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this was the clang version I was using, `clang-r383902b`.  Setting my local manifest to pull from `master` and using `clang-r399163b` everything worked.

Specifically:

1. **Extend** the clang prebuid project in a local manifest

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote name="aosp" fetch="https://android.googlesource.com/" review="https://android-review.googlesource.com/" />
  <extend-project path="prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86" name="platform/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86" groups="trusty" revision="refs/heads/master" clone-depth="1" remote="aosp" />
</manifest>
```

2. **Sync**: `repo sync -d prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86`
3. **Re-push**: `CLANG_TAG=clang-r399163b adb push prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/${CLANG_TAG}/runtimes_ndk_cxx/aarch64/lldb-server /data/local/tmp/lldb-server` (or whatever the newest tag is)
4. **Re-run** `lldb-server`

I experimented with using the newest `lldb-server` with the existing `lldb` and it still worked.